# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(4n)}{8n}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(4n)}{8n}$$

I thought that we can use Dirichlet's test when $a_n=\frac{1}{8n}$ monotonic decreasing to zero and $b_n=\sin^2(4n)$ is bounded $|\sin^2(4n)|<1$

But in the result it is says that it diverges

Comment: For Dirichlet's test you need there to be some $M\ge0$ such that$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N b_n\right|\le M\qquad\forall N\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: $\sin^24n=\dfrac{1-\cos8n}{2}$. First term diverges, and second converges by Dirichlet. All series diverges.

Comment: Relate $\sin^2(x)$ to $\cos(2x)$, then use Dirichlet test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$\max(\sin^24n,\sin^24(n+1))\ge m>0.$$

Hence, if you take the terms in pairs,

$$\frac{\sin^24n}{n}+\frac{\sin^24(n+1)}{n+1}\ge \frac m{n+1}$$

and the series is bounded below by an Harmonic one.

Answer (score 1):

We use the identity $$\sin^2(4n)=\frac{1-\cos(8n)}{2}$$,which gives $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(4n)}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n} -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{cos(8n)}{2n} $$. We shall show that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{cos(8n)}{2n} $$ diverges, which since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n} $$ is a divergent harmonic series and since a divergent series $\pm$  a convergent series diverges, will show that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(4n)}{n}$$ diverges.
We’ll use the ‘forward difference’ notation. If h is a function defined on the integers,  $\Delta h $will denote the function defined by $\Delta h(n)=h(n+1)-h(n)$The summation by parts formula is $$\sum_{n=a}^b f(n)  \Delta g(n)=f(b+1)g(b+1)-f(a)g(a)- \sum_{n=a}^b (\Delta f(n))g(n+1) $$.This formula, together with $$\cos (kn)=\Delta (\frac {\sin (k(n-\frac{1}{2}))}{2 \sin (k/2)})$$ and 
$$\Delta (\frac{1}{n})=-\frac{1}{(n+1)n} $$gives $$ \sum_{n=1}^b \frac{\cos (8n)}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^b \frac{1}{n}\Delta (\frac{\sin(8(n-\frac{1}{2}))}{2\sin4})$$
 $$=\frac{1}{2\sin4}(\frac{\sin(8b+4)}{b+1}-\sin 4+\sum_{n=1}^b \frac{\sin (8n+4)}{n(n+1)} )$$ Taking limits as $b \rightarrow \infty$, we see that convergence/divergence of 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(8n)}{n}$$ is equivalent to the convergence/divergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(8n+4)}{n(n+1)}  $$ Since this last series is absolutely convergent by comparison with the convergent p-series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$, the series  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(8n)}{n}$$ also converges. We conclude that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(4n)}{n}$$ diverges.